# Form labels translation key with parameters

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form in symfony2 where I add a checkbox for let's say "Terms and Conditions" that needs to be checked. I want to add a link to "Terms and Conditions" label which I want to pass it as a parameter, let's say %url% like this

> messages.en.yml

```
site.terms: Hiermit akzeptiere ich die <a href="%url%">AGB</a>
```

> In the Form type I have something like this

```
$builder
...
->add('terms', 'checkbox', [
    'constraints' => [
        new True()
    ],
    'label' => 'site.terms'
]);
```

So the question is how can I add that url parameter or even an array of parameters to the form label.

For avoiding escaping the HTML inside the form label I have overwritten the block label like this:

```
{% block form_label %}
    {% if not compound %}
        {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if required %}
        {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if label is empty %}
        {% set label = name|humanize %}
    {% endif %}

    {# added raw to avoid HTML Escaping #}
    <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain)|raw }}</label>
{% endblock form_label %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I didn't have the time to look deeply into the possibility of changing the label rendering and using a added argument to the form field as the translation parameters.

However, my quick-fix was to render the label manually and change the label by passing it as an argument:

```
{# custom twig extention to get the url for a page #}
{% set url = get_path_by_internal_name('tos', app.request.locale) %}
{{ form_label(terms, 'site.terms'|trans({'%url%': url})|raw) }}
```